# Order array with dates

Tags: php

I have array with a values like this

```
04|2012
05|2011
05|2011
06|2011
08|2011
```

In fact these are dates. The problem is that I can`t figure out how to order them descending

Comment: is this your array key values???

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that that format represents `month|year` and you're running PHP 5.3+:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $toTime = function ($str) {
        list($month, $year) = explode('|', $str);
        return mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    }

    $a = $toTime($a);
    $b = $toTime($b);

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use SQL-like date format (yyyy-mm-dd) then you may sort dates directly as strings in any order.

If date format can't change:

```
<?php

$a = array(
    '04|2012',
    '05|2011',
    '05|2011',
    '06|2011',
    '08|2011',
);


function compare_strange_dates($date1, $date2) {
    return strcmp(
        implode('-', array_reverse(explode('|', $date1))),
        implode('-', array_reverse(explode('|', $date2)))
    );
}

usort($a, 'compare_strange_dates'); // ascending
$d = array_reverse($a); // descending

var_dump($a);
var_dump($d);
```

If you want only descending order, swap $date1 and $date2 in compare_strange_dates() return statement and use only usort.

Answer (score 1):

With `$dates` being your array, you can do ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DwMyNY))

```
usort($dates, function($a, $b) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('m\|Y', $b)->format('U')
         - DateTime::createFromFormat('m\|Y', $a)->format('U');
});
print_r($dates);
```

An alternative that doesnt require converting to dates and should be quicker, would be ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/T5RNZv))

```
usort($dates, function($a, $b) {
    return preg_replace('#(\d{2})\|(\d{4})#', '$2$1', $b)
         - preg_replace('#(\d{2})\|(\d{4})#', '$2$1', $a);
});
print_r($dates);
```

Both output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 04|2012
    [1] => 08|2011
    [2] => 06|2011
    [3] => 05|2011
    [4] => 05|2011
)
```

Note: all of these require PHP 5.3+ due to the lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort using only this 2 items from the array, you can concatenate year and days in a single item in a one dimension array of integers and having something like:

```
201204
201105
201105
201106
201108
```

and after this sort it like an ussual one dimensional array, but in descending order.